# error with ng-repeat when replacing $scope with this keyword and controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've transitioned from using the `$scope` object to `vm = this` in controllers. I understand you have to then state a `controllerAs` in either the `view` or the `state`.

I have two tables using `ng-repeat`, and the first one works fine, all data is populated, but the second for some reason doesn't. I have had a play around and the item the user clicks on is logged in the console, but the second table isn't populated with the data. Was working fine with `$scope`.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider',  function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('/', '/patents/')
        .otherwise('/patents/');

    $stateProvider
        .state("patents", {
            url: "/patents",
            templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/list-patents.htm",
            controller: "patentCtrl",
            controllerAs: "patents"
        })
        .state("patents.item", {
            url: "/:id",
            templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm",
            controller: "patentCtrl",
            controllerAs: "item"
        })
}]);

app.factory('patentsService', function($http, $q) {

    var factory = {};

        var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/Sprint002b/restpatent/';

        factory.fetchAllPatents = function() {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
             $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching Users');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        factory.select = function(item) { 
            selectedItem = item;
            return selectedItem;
        }        

    return factory;

});

app.controller('patentCtrl', ['patentsService', function(patentsService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.patent={id:null, patentApplicationNumber:'', clientRef: '', renewalStatus: '', currentRenewalCost: '', costBandEndDate:'', renewalCostNextStage:'', renewalDueDate:''};
    vm.patents=[];

    vm.select = function(item) {
       vm.patentItem = patentsService.select(item); //THIS SHOULD POPULATE TABLE
       console.log(vm.patentItem)
    }

    vm.fetchAllPatents = function(){

        patentsService.fetchAllPatents()
            .then(
            function(d) {
                vm.patents = d;
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching Users');
            }
        );
    }

    vm.fetchAllPatents();

}]);
```

**working table**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in patents.patents">
        <td ng-click="patents.select(x)"><a ui-sref="patents.item({id: x.id})">{{x.applicationNumber}}</a></td>
        <td ng-bind="x.clientRef"></td>
        <td ng-bind="x.currentRenewalCost">$</td>
        <td ng-bind="x.costBandEndDate"></td>
        <td ng-bind="x.renewalCostNextStage"></td>
        <td ng-bind="x.renewalDueDate"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**broken table**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in item.patentItem">
        <td>{{x.applicationNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{x.clientRef}}</td>
        <td>{{x.renewalStatus}}</td>
        <td>{{x.costBandEndDate}}</td>
        <td>{{x.renewalCostNextStage}}</td>
        <td>{{x.renewalDueDate}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should create a new separate controller for `patents.item` state. Where on load you are going to just retrieve current selected item from `patentsService`.

```
//config
.state("patents.item", {
    url: "/:id",
    templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm",
    controller: "patentItem", //<-- controller added here
    controllerAs: "item"
})
//patenItem new controller
.controller('patentItem', ['patentsService', function(patentsService) {
    var item = this;
    item.select = function(items) {
        vm.patentItem = patentsService.select(item);
        console.log(vm.patentItem)
    };
    function init(){
       item.select();
    }
    init();
}]);
```

Comment: It comes back with `TypeError: Cannot set property 'patentItem' of undefined`. How will the `select` function be called if it is invoked from a different controller bound to that template?

Comment: @PankajParker whats the reason that `$scope` worked but using `vm` keyword doesn't?